# Question about the dots on Quartile groups in boxplot

Tags: r, rna-seq, microarray, ggplot2

I have Microarray Normalized Expression data for a specific Gene. It looks like below in a dataframe `B`

```
SampleID    Gene    Type
Sample1     5.02    Tumor
Sample2     5.06    Tumor
Sample3     5.1     Tumor
Sample4     5.11    Tumor
Sample5    5.127    Normal
Sample6     5.12    Normal
Sample7    5.138    Normal
Sample8    5.149    Normal
```

I see that the minimum expression value in the table is 5.0 and maximum expression value is around 5.9.

I wanted to show the expression between two conditions with a boxplot and used following code.

```
q <- ggboxplot(B, x = "Type", y = "Gene",
               color = "black", palette = "npg",
               add = "jitter", ylab = 'Gene expression', xlab=FALSE,
               order=c("Normal", "Tumor"))
q + stat_compare_means(method = "t.test") + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_n_text()
```

This gave a plot like this [image: Boxplot1]

But when I remove the `jitter` from the code,

```
q <- ggboxplot(B, x = "Type", y = "Gene",
               color = "black", palette = "npg",
               ylab = 'Gene expression', xlab=FALSE,
               order=c("Normal", "Tumor"))
q + stat_compare_means(method = "t.test") + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_n_text()
```

I see many black dots in the middle of the boxplot like this [image: Boxplot2]

May I know why I see those dots in the second boxplot after removing the jitter. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: I don't know from where does the `ggboxplot` function comes from or `stat_compare_means`? Also please, continue [edit]ing the question to clarify the question. It is still unclear to me if you want to remove some points, add them or something else

Comment: from the package ggpubr

Comment: I am confused by the wording in "May I know why I see those dots in the second boxplot after removing the jitter. Is there a way to avoid that?" Are you trying to ask  "Why did the points not disappear after I remove jitter?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add the points with `geom_point()`. Just remove it and you will get your "empty" boxplot.

```
q <- ggboxplot(B, x = "Type", y = "Gene",
               color = "black", palette = "npg",
               ylab = 'Gene expression', xlab=FALSE,
               order=c("Normal", "Tumor"))
```

Unfortunately I couldn't use `stat_compare_means(method = "t.test")` and     `stat_n_text()`, but this two just add the labels.

[image]

Comment: yes, this is the mistake I'm doing. I removed geom_point(). It looks fine now. thanq